# $('p').remove(); doesn't work, why?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code, and what I'm trying to do is to add values as "items" with `.append()` method, that i take from an input text box, and then input them into a div with "lista" as classname after clicking on a div with "boton" as id. This all works fine, the problem comes when I try to remove the item that I added with `$('this').remove();` that doesn't do anything.

Is there any reason of why that isn't working? I'd appreciate any help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contador = 1;
    $('#boton').click(function(){
    var item = $("input:text").val();
        if (item !== ""){
            $('.lista').append("<p style ='cursor:pointer;'>"+contador+"º) "+
            $("input:text").val()+"</p>")
            contador++;
        }
    });  

    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here since your paragraph has been added dynamically:

```
$('.lista').on('click', 'p', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

This will helps you to bind `click` event to these newly created paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as the elements are created dynamically

```
$('.lista').on('click', 'p', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dynamically creating new 'p' element, you should use Jquery [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers to the element.

```
    $(".lista" ).on( "click", "p", function()
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

Comment: How is your answer any different from the other two?

Comment: These two answers were not there when I started answering. As I am fast only two people crossed me this time.